# Can I change the resolution logic for Route-Model-Binding to always lowercase the string key?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, routes

I am using UUID keys in a Laravel 5.7 project, and it works really well.

When requesting an item from the database through a route, the key is looked up and compared as a string. When the request sends the uuid string in uppercase the route model binding will not find the model though as Laravel's UUID strings are lowercase.

Is there a way to make sure that the key is lowercased before the find query is executed?

The documentation explains that I can customize the resolution logic like this:

```
Route::bind('user', function ($value) {
    return App\User::where('name', $value)->first() ?? abort(404);
});
```

however this is useless, as it applies only to specific wildcards (here 'user') but I need this to apply to every binding and also the class is then dynamic of course.

Is there a way to customize that behavior or can someone point me to the code where Laravel does the dynamic resolution?

**I DO NOT want to fall back to just taking the identifier from the url and then do the find myself in every route. I really want to change the behavior for all route model bindings.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Override `resolveRouteBinding()` in your model(s):

```php
public function resolveRouteBinding($value)
{
    return $this->where($this->getRouteKeyName(), strtolower($value))->first();
}
```