# Laravel - How to show details of a soft deleted model

Tags: laravel

I'm using soft delete in my model `quotation`. Deleting the `quotation` keeps the row in the DB with a `deleted_at` field.

I updated my index method to include soft deleted models:

```
    public function index()
    {
        $quotations = Quotation::withTrashed()->orderBy("id", "asc")->paginate(100);

        return view('quotations.index', compact('quotations'));
    }
```

But my show method is not working, I'm getting a 404 Model Not Found error:

```php
    public function show(Quotation $quotation)
    {
        $quotation = Quotation::withTrashed()->find($quotation->id);
        return view('quotations.show', compact('quotation', 'activities'));
    }
```

Comment: `404 Model Not Found error` do you mean Class  `Quotation` not found? If so then `use App\Quotation` on top of the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [route-model-binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding), it will automatically find the `$id` from Model `Quotation` without `withTrashed()` and inject to variable `$quotation`. so the matching model instance `$quotation` is not found in the database, a 404 HTTP response is automatically generated.:

```php
$quotation = Quotation::find($id);
```

#### Solution 1:

So you can try to use `$id` directly

```php
    public function show($id)
    {
        $quotation = Quotation::withTrashed()->find($id);
        return view('quotations.show', compact('quotation', 'activities'));
    }
```

And change your route from `{quotation}` to `{id}`.

#### Solution 2:

Customizing the resolution logic:

```php
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::bind('quotation', function ($value) {
        return App\Quotation::withTrashed()->where('id', $value)->first() ?? abort(404);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get id by using the following:

```
public function show() {
    $quotation = Quotation::withTrashed()->where('id',2)->get();
    return $quotation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to apply it to a single model you can do this. Override the method resolveRouteBinding in your model (this works with Laravel 8):

```
/**
 * Retrieve the model for a bound value.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @param  string|null  $field
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
 */
public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null)
{
    return $this->withTrashed()->where($field ?? $this->getRouteKeyName(), $value)->first();
}
```

Related: [Can I change the resolution logic for Route-Model-Binding to always lowercase the string key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52746883/can-i-change-the-resolution-logic-for-route-model-binding-to-always-lowercase-th).